# enumerate all matches in file with sed or perl

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have next file:

```
:~$ cat test
        <Set Id="16">
                <Ver="44" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="" Collision="no">
        </Set>        
        <Set Id="17">
                <Ver="22" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="" Collision="no">
        </Set>
```

and I need to increment B2vpnId value in file, I found a way how to get this change in output:

```
:~$ i=1;while read -r line; do echo "$line"|sed -e 's/B2vpnId=""/B2vpnId="'"vpn$i"'"/';((i+=1));done <<< "$(cat test|grep B2vpnId=)"
<Ver="44" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn1" Collision="no">
<Ver="22" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn2" Collision="no">
```

but since I have many other config lines I need this change in file itself and cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: Welcome, this is better suited for `awk`, is there a reason why you would not use it?

Comment: Don't use a shell script for this.  If you must use a shell script, use it as a wrapper around awk or perl or something - don't use a while read loop to pipe individual lines into sed, awk, grep, perl, they're all far more capable of processing multi-line input than bash is.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696)

Comment: If the input is XML, could you please update the document in the question so that it is a representative sample from your actual file?  The current document is not well-formed XML (missing root node, invalid `Ver` tags, and missing closing tags).  This operation is trivial with an XML parser, but not if the document is faulty.

Answer (score 2):

Using `perl`'s `/e` regex modifier to evaluate the replacement portion of the `s/search/replace/` operator as perl code:

```
$ perl -p -e 's/B2vpnId=""/sprintf "B2vpnId=\"vpn%i\"", ++$i/e' test 
        <Set Id="16">
                <Ver="44" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn1" Collision="no">
        </Set>
        <Set Id="17">
                <Ver="22" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn2" Collision="no">
        </Set>
```

If you want it to change the files on disk (rather than just output to stdout), use perl's `-i` option.

If you are processing multiple files and want it to reset the counter (`$i`) after each file, add `; $i=0 if eof` to the end of the script:

```
$ cp test test2
$ perl -p -e 's/B2vpnId=""/sprintf "B2vpnId=\"vpn%i\"", ++$i/e; $i=0 if eof' test test2
        <Set Id="16">
                <Ver="44" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn1" Collision="no">
        </Set>
        <Set Id="17">
                <Ver="22" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn2" Collision="no">
        </Set>

        <Set Id="16">
                <Ver="44" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn1" Collision="no">
        </Set>
        <Set Id="17">
                <Ver="22" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn2" Collision="no">
        </Set>
```

Without the `$i=0 if eof` statement, the second copy of test would have B2vpnIDs of "vpn3" and "vpn4".

BTW, if you want the counter to start from a different number, e.g. 10, then add `BEGIN { $i=9 };` to the beginning of the script.  `BEGIN` blocks are executed only once before any of the input is read.   The rest of the script is executed repeatedly, once for each input line.  BTW, there are other kinds of code blocks that are only executed once - from `man perlsyn`:

> When a block is preceded by a compilation phase keyword such as `BEGIN`,
> `END`, `INIT`, `CHECK`, or `UNITCHECK`, then the   block will run only
> during the corresponding phase of execution.  See `perlmod` for more details.

Remember that `$i` will be incremented **before** it is used each time (because the script is using `++$i` rather than `$i++`, which would increment it after each use), so subtract 1 from the starting number.

Also remember to change the `$i=0 if eof` to match the BEGIN block, e.g., `$i=9 if eof` if you're using that.

```
$ perl -p -e 'BEGIN { $i=9 };
              s/B2vpnId=""/sprintf "B2vpnId=\"vpn%i\"", ++$i/e;
              $i=9 if eof' test
```

Or, since we're now using a BEGIN block to initialise $i, we can post-increment it (and use another variable for the starting value so we only have to change it in one place).

```
$ perl -p -e 'BEGIN { $start = 10; $i = $start };
              s/B2vpnId=""/sprintf "B2vpnId=\"vpn%i\"", $i++/e;
              $i = $start if eof' test
```

or even set it to a default value of 1, then **if** the first arg isn't an existing file set it to the first arg :

```
$ perl -p -e 'BEGIN {
                $start = 1;
                $start = shift unless -f $ARGV[0];
                $i = $start
              };

              s/B2vpnId=""/sprintf "B2vpnId=\"vpn%i\"", $i++/e;

              $i = $start if eof' 10 test*
```

Answer (score 1):

This is better suited for `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk 'BEGIN { c=1 } /B2vpnId/ { sub(/vpnId="/, "vpnId=\"vpn"c,$0); c++ }1' test
        <Set Id="16">
                <Ver="44" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn1" Collision="no">
        </Set>        
        <Set Id="17">
                <Ver="22" Sniff="no" B2vpnId="vpn2" Collision="no">
        </Set>
```

To actually change the file (GNU `awk`):

```
$ awk -i inplace <rest of command>
```

---

Note: See [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat);

Comment: Thx, very useful and simple, awk is perfect tool for my case - it is easy to understand its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to re-direct your output to a temp-file and then move the temp-file over the original file.

I am, however a bit surprised by your complicated command line.

```
i=1
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"|sed -e 's/B2vpnId=""/B2vpnId="'"vpn$i"'"/'
    ((i+=1))
done <<< "$(cat test|grep B2vpnId=)"
```

A simpler way would be:

```
i=1
grep 'B2vpnId=' test |
while read -r line; do 
    echo "$line"|sed -e 's/B2vpnId=""/B2vpnId="'"vpn$i"'"/'
    ((i+=1))
done
```

However, if you need to echo also the lines that will not be changed, you should probably put the `grep` in the loop.

```
i=1
while read -r line; do 
    if echo "$line" | grep -q 'B2vpnId=' ; then
        echo "$line"|sed -e 's/B2vpnId=""/B2vpnId="'"vpn$i"'"/'
        ((i+=1))
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < test
```

This is working from your own solution.

Comment: In your last example, you could avoid the `grep` and the additional `else` condition by doing something such as: ```echo "$line" | sed -e '/B2vpnId=/{s/B2vpnId=""/B2vpnId="'"vpn$i"'"/; q0}; q1' && ((i+=1))```. Sed will return 0 if `B2vpnId=` appears in the line and increment the `$i`, and will return 1 if it didn't match the condition without incrementing `$i`.